# Query manufacturer revenue for the past year

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replicate a client's sales stats spreadsheet, but using the schema we have built.

The spreadsheet looks like this:

```
Month  | Manufacturer A | Manufacturer B | Manufacturer C | ... etc

Jan-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Feb-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Mar-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Apr-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
May-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Jun-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Jul-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Aug-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Sept-17| £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Oct-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Nov-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
Dec-17 | £40,000        | £50,000        | £60,000        |
```

And my schema looks like this:

```
Manufacturers:

id, name

Orders:

id, number, made (order date)

Items:

id, order_id, manufacturer_id, name, price
```

How can I get the totals for each manufacturer for each month?

Comment: You need a "pivot" functionality, not available natively in MySQL. You can simulate it -- if you know the number of manufacturers beforehand.

Comment: @TheImpaler Could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: Google mysql pivot.

Comment: I'm familiar with pivot tables, but for some reason I can't think what it would contain in this case

Answer (score 1):

You need a "pivot" functionality, not available natively in MySQL.

This is probably not the answer you wanted, but it's the one I use sometimes. You can *somewhat simulate* a pivot if you know the number of manufacturers beforehand.

It requires a long query, though, that I sometimes implement using dynamic SQL.

For example:

```
select
  year(o.order_date),
  month(o.order_date),
  sum(case when m.id = 'A' then i.price end) as 'Manufacturer A',
  sum(case when m.id = 'B' then i.price end) as 'Manufacturer B',
  ...
from orders o
join items i on i.order_id = o.id
join manufacturers m on m.id = i.manufacturer_id
group by year(o.order_date), month(o.order_date)
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go. Manufacturer A, B, etc were just examples. Is there any way I can use the names in the manufacturers table?

Comment: Unfortunately the `id` and `name` of the manufacturers are hard coded in this solution. It's not real pivoting, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuring that you know the list of all manufacturers, you can use conditional aggregation. The following query demonstrates how to do this with 2 manufacturers, A and B :

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(o.made, '%b-%y'),
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.name = 'Manufacturer A' THEN i.price ELSE 0 END) "Manufacturer A",
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.name = 'Manufacturer B' THEN i.price ELSE 0 END) "Manufacturer B"
FROM
    orders o
    LEFT JOIN items i
        ON  o.order_id = i.id
    LEFT JOIN manufacters m
        ON manufacter_id = m.id
GROUP BY month(o.made)
```